# Increase number of websites for organization

Tags: summaryfields

I would like to include more than five websites to an organization's profile summary. After adding a fifth website, the option to “Add” a new website is no longer available. How can I include more than five websites to an organization's profile?

The organization has several of the included options, e.g., “Main”, “Twitter”, “Slack”, “Facebook”, “LinkedIn”, “Instagram”, plus custom options I've added, “GitHub”, “Wiki”, etc., and I would like to include a URL of each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That limit only applies to the in-place edit feature. Just click the edit button at the top of the page to edit the whole contact and you can add as many as you want.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted to do.